# sed -e "\$aDNS3=" won't save the DNS3= to the file

Tags: bash

```
sed -e "\$aDNS3=" <filedirectory>
```

I'm trying to add in the line "DNS3=" in to the end of the file, so after executing the command in a bash script, it opens the file and include the DNS3= into the last line but did not save the changes. Is there anyway to save the changes and also not show the changes made?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-i` option. This will edit the file in-place.

From `man sed`:

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

Using `sed -e "\$aDNS3=" -i filename` would set `DNS3=` into the last line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "DNS=" >> file
```

would be a lot simpler, and faster because it does not need to read the file.

Comment: Only problem with this is text files lacking a newline at the end.

Comment: @jthill: strictly speaking, a file not terminated with a newline is not a text file. It's true that you should know what you're appending to, but `echo >> file` is the classic idiom for appending.

Comment: No question there, it's only when a file might have been touched by an untrusted user that the extra sanitization becomes sane.